# windows interface to track selected or pointed word/line/paragraph

Tags: windows, winapi

Does anybody knows how to get the paragraph the user is pointing his mouse to? It shouldn't depend on application that is used.

A good example are dictionary apps that will translate the word when you right-click on it while holding ctrl.

I'm curious how they are doing that, because I'm thinking about creating word learning tool that will also remember the sentence where the new word was encountered.

Thanks.

UPDATE: 
[capture selected text from other applications problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513883/capture-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at employing an Accessibility API (e.g. used by screen readers for blind persons.)  See the [UI Automation page at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753107.aspx) for usage details.